# (Xamarin.Forms) The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Ok this problem may have issed a long time ago but none of the solution that have been mentiond have worked for me, like deleting the bin and obj file then restart `vs` or reinstall `vs`.

Im trying to debug my application on my samsung device and this is the error im getting.
My samsung Device is `samsung S9` and android version is `9`.

Im not trying to deploy my application simple trying to debug the application, so im assuming that there is no need for `CERTIFICATES` where i have not even enabled it on my android project.
This problem have happend to sudden, so i have no idee how it happend.

```
  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       ADB0010: The package was not properly signed (NO_CERTIFICATES).
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\1549\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 333
       at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\1549\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

> **Update and solution**
>
> I have already figured out the problem. There was `keystore` settings
>   in the `csproj` file, even though, the custom keystore settings was
>   not enable it still tried to look at those settings. And there is no
>   way to detect those settings without openings the `csproj` file So all
>   i did was remove those settings and everythings worked.

Comment: Have you tested on other devices or emulators? And this could be a JDK's issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524581/xamarin-android-app-signing-does-not-work. Have you tried that workaround?

Comment: Nope but got the solution now, read the update